# AWS Kubernetes error while trying to access nodes and resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I recently created a kube cluster in AWS and worked perfectly well. Please note that I created this cluster for training purposes therefore, I have shut down the servers after playing it around. When I spin up my ec2 instances (1 master and 1 worker node) , I am getting a below error staying an i/o time out.

```
root@ip-172-xx-xx-xx:/home/ubuntu# kubectl get nodes
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 52.xx.xx.xx:6443: i/o timeout
```

Can you please help? Much appreciated.

I actually checked security group settings and verified that I have opened the port 6443 already.

Comment: This issue was resolved after allocating an elastic ip.